# Escaping characters in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, escaping, ansi-escape

I want to replace all special characters in a string with their escaped equivalences (`\n \t \\ \"`). My idea is to use reader and writer and then put `\\` before any special character. I use an dynamic array/char pointer.

Since I am not so confident in my understanding of pointers I still tend to use sometimes more often arrays than pointers.

As usual with C I get mostly (only) garbage as an output. Where do I get this undefined behavior from? My code so far:

```
char *escapeChars(const char *src)
{
    int i, counter = 0, j = 0;
    size_t size = strlen(src) + 1;
    char pr[size], *pw;
    pr[0] = '\0';

    strcat(pr, src);  /*to get the constness away*/
    pw = pr;
    for(i = 0; i < ((int) sizeof(pr)); i++){
            if(pr[i] == '\n' || pr[i] == '\t' || pr[i] == '\\' || pr[i] == '\"'){
                    counter++;
            }
    }
    pw = malloc(sizeof(pr) + (size_t) counter);

    for(i = 0; i <((int) sizeof(pr)); i++){
            if(pr[i] != '\n' || pr[i] != '\t' || pr[i] != '\\' || pr[i] != '\"'){
                    pw[i+j] = pr[i];
            } else {
                    pw[i+j] = '\\';
                    pw[i+j+1] = pr[i];
                    j++;
            }
    }
    pw[i + j] = '\0';
    return pw;
}
```

As an output I get totally wrong stuff. And I believe it fails when encounters the first special chararacter.

```
Original string: Some
string   with "special characters". And \.
Result: Some
str
```

If anything is even slightly unclear, notify me.

Comment: For one thing, the if ... not equals expression on line 18 will be problematic.  It will always return true.

Comment: Can you please show exactly how `escapeChars` is being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to special case the replacement of `'\n'` to `'\\'` + `'n'` etc.

There is no need to make a local copy of `src` to scan for special characters.  You can simplify the code this way:

```
char *escapeChars(const char *src) {
    int i, j;
    char *pw;

    for (i = j = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (src[i] == '\n' || src[i] == '\t' ||
            src[i] == '\\' || src[i] == '\"') {
            j++;
        }
    }
    pw = malloc(i + j + 1);

    for (i = j = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        switch (src[i]) {
        case '\n': pw[i+j] = '\\'; pw[i+j+1] = 'n'; j++; break;
        case '\t': pw[i+j] = '\\'; pw[i+j+1] = 't'; j++; break;
        case '\\': pw[i+j] = '\\'; pw[i+j+1] = '\\'; j++; break;
        case '\"': pw[i+j] = '\\'; pw[i+j+1] = '\"'; j++; break;
        default:   pw[i+j] = src[i]; break;
        }
    }
    pw[i+j] = '\0';
    return pw;
}
```

Note that you should also escape some other characters: `'\r'`, and the non printing or non portable characters in the range 1 to 31 and 127 to 255 for ASCII.  Escaping these as octal sequences is more work but manageable at your skill level.

Comment: but `pr` is declared as a char array, so `sizeof(pr)` would be the number of elements + 1. Or?

Comment: That's correct.  I amended the answer. It is confusing to use `sizeof(pr)`, especially since this array has a dynamic size (VLA) and is not really needed for the purpose of the function.

Comment: is str the same as src?

Comment: one more thing: in the 5th line, it gives that pr is not initialized, could that lead to segmentation fault (because I am getting one) and do you know a quick fix about `pr`? Like `pr = src` ? But then I get `discarded qualifier const`

Comment: No, I simply forgot to amend the code I pasted from your sample.  These is no `pr` array in my code, `str[i]` is tested directly, no need to copy the content of `str` as it is not modified.